# How to replace some values with max values from cumsum within groups

Tags: r, cumsum

I am trying to calculate a cumulative sum for students that have been exposed to a support network during their schooling.

A sample dataframe would be (ID=student, Term=semester of interest, Support=Exposure to support network):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(123451, 123451, 123451, 123451, 123452, 123452, 123452, 123452, 
                      123452, 123452, 123452, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453),
                 Term= c(1141, 1148, 1158, 1141, 1158, 1161, 1148, 1151, 1158, 1138, 
                         1141, 1138, 1141, 1141, 1148, 1138, 1148, 1158, 1161), 
                 Support = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

Since I am looking for cumulative exposure (starting from their earliest semester) I first ordered the data by ID and by Term:
`df <- df[order(df[,1], df[,2]),]`

I then calculated a cumulative sum for the Support variable into a separate column

`df$Dosage <- ave(df[3], df[1], FUN=cumsum)`

Output:

```
       ID Term Support Dosage
1  123451 1141       1       1
4  123451 1141       1       2
2  123451 1148       0       2
3  123451 1158       1       3
10 123452 1138       0       0
11 123452 1141       0       0
7  123452 1148       1       1
8  123452 1151       1       2
5  123452 1158       1       3
9  123452 1158       1       4
6  123452 1161       0       4
12 123453 1138       1       1
16 123453 1138       0       1
13 123453 1141       0       1
14 123453 1141       1       2
15 123453 1148       0       2
17 123453 1148       1       3
18 123453 1158       1       4
19 123453 1161       1       5
```

While this is useful, in the event that a student has two rows for the same semester, I would like the value for Dosage to reflect the maximum value.

So for Student=123451 and Term=1141 I would like both Dosage values to equal 2.

For Student=123452 and Term=1158, I would like both Dosage values to equal 4.

For Student=123453 and Term=1148, I would like both Dosage values to equal 3.

Expected Output:

```
       ID Term Support Dosage
1  123451 1141       1       2
4  123451 1141       1       2
2  123451 1148       0       2
3  123451 1158       1       3
10 123452 1138       0       0
11 123452 1141       0       0
7  123452 1148       1       1
8  123452 1151       1       2
5  123452 1158       1       4
9  123452 1158       1       4
6  123452 1161       0       4
12 123453 1138       1       1
16 123453 1138       0       1
13 123453 1141       0       2
14 123453 1141       1       2
15 123453 1148       0       3
17 123453 1148       1       3
18 123453 1158       1       4
19 123453 1161       1       5
```

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: I added the expected output.  Thank you for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite understand what your problem is, but maybe you can try this:

```
library(dplyr)


df <- data.frame(ID=c(123451, 123451, 123451, 123451, 123452, 123452, 123452, 123452, 
                      123452, 123452, 123452, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453, 123453),
                 Term= c(1141, 1148, 1158, 1141, 1158, 1161, 1148, 1151, 1158, 1138, 
                         1141, 1138, 1141, 1141, 1148, 1138, 1148, 1158, 1161), 
                 Support = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))


df %>% 
  arrange(ID, Term) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Dosage = cumsum(Support)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID, Term) %>%
  mutate(Dosage = max(Dosage)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
       ID  Term Support Dosage
 1 123451  1141       1      2
 2 123451  1141       1      2
 3 123451  1148       0      2
 4 123451  1158       1      3
 5 123452  1138       0      0
 6 123452  1141       0      0
 7 123452  1148       1      1
 8 123452  1151       1      2
 9 123452  1158       1      4
10 123452  1158       1      4
11 123452  1161       0      4
12 123453  1138       1      1
13 123453  1138       0      1
14 123453  1141       0      2
15 123453  1141       1      2
16 123453  1148       0      3
17 123453  1148       1      3
18 123453  1158       1      4
19 123453  1161       1      5
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!